# wagon-maven-plugin:1.0:download-single cannot download a resource

Tags: maven, maven-wagon-plugin

I want to use wagon-maven-plugin with download-single goal from a correct url but maven says:

`Error handling resource: Resource missing at http://myurl/from/file%3FWSDL 404 Not Found -> [Help 1]`

Here is the plugin definition:

```
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>wagon-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>fetch-wsdl</id>
                                <phase>initialize</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>download-single</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <url>http://myurl</url>
                                    <fromFile>from/file?WSDL</fromFile>
                                    <toFile>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/Consumer.wsdl</toFile>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
```

The problem here is I have a query symbol in my url but wagon-maven-plugin replace it by %3F.

for example: It converts `http://myurl/from/file?WSDL` to `http://myurl/from/file%3FWSDL`

Are there anyone who face this issue as well?

Note: If I use with another url without query symbol it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, It is a known issue that it does not work with query symbol. I am going to use another plugin [maven-download-plugin](https://github.com/maven-download-plugin/maven-download-plugin).